# How to traverse a graph both "forwards" and "backwards"?

Tags: java, graph-traversal, jgrapht

I am investigating Graphs/Graph Traversals using

```
compile group: 'org.jgrapht', name: 'jgrapht-core', version: '1.1.0'
```

Using the code below I can create a simple graph

```
final Graph<String, DefaultEdge> directedGraph = new DefaultDirectedGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
directedGraph.addVertex("v1");
directedGraph.addVertex("v2");
directedGraph.addVertex("v3");
directedGraph.addVertex("v4");

directedGraph.addEdge("v1", "v4");
directedGraph.addEdge("v4", "v2");
directedGraph.addEdge("v2", "v3");
```

and traverse it "forwards"

```
TopologicalOrderIterator<String, DefaultEdge> topologicalOrderIterator = new TopologicalOrderIterator<>(directedGraph);
System.out.println("topologicalOrderIterator");
while (topologicalOrderIterator.hasNext()) {

    System.out.println(topologicalOrderIterator.next());

}
```

However I would also like to be able to "retrace" my steps back through the graph from any vertex and return to the "start" of the graph.

e.g. `topologicalOrderIterator.previous()`

I cannot see any obvious methods within `jgrapht-core`?

Is reverse Graph traversal possible? (logical?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TopologicalOrderIterator` doesn't have a `previous()` method. An easy way to fix this, is to implement your own iterator which extends the TopologicalOrderIterator and which maintains a memory of items you encountered. Here is an untested, poorly formatted example:

```
public class ReversibleTopoIterator extends TopologicalOrderIterator{
    Stack<V> back=new ...
    Stack<V> front=new ...

    public V next(){
        V v;
        if(front.isEmpty())
            v=super.next();
        else
            v=front.pop();
        back.push(v);
        return v;
    }
    public V previous(){
        V v=back.pop();
        front.push(v);
        return v;
    }
    public boolean hasNext(){return !front.isEmpty() || super.hasNext()};
    public boolean hasPrevious(){return !back.isEmpty()}
}
```

In summary, you maintain 2 stacks `back` and `front`. If you move forward using the `next()` method, you first empty the `front` stack, and then ask the `TopologicalOrderIterator` for new elements. All items obtained with `next()` are pushed onto the `back` stack. Similarly, if you move backward using the `previous()` method, you pop items of the `back` stack. All items obtained with the `previous()` method are pushed onto the `front` stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EdgeReversedGraph` to create a "edge-reversed" view (i.e. sources are now targets and vice versa) then use the same iterators as you use for the normal graph.

https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org.jgrapht.core/org/jgrapht/graph/EdgeReversedGraph.html

```java
TopologicalOrderIterator<String, DefaultEdge> topologicalOrderIterator = new TopologicalOrderIterator<>(new EdgeReversedGraph(directedGraph));
System.out.println("topologicalOrderIterator");
while (topologicalOrderIterator.hasNext()) {

    System.out.println(topologicalOrderIterator.next());

}
```